# Sending Data from android app to Website and returning result onto App

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to implement a feature for my app where I have a value, say mileage on a car, and what I want to do with this value is pass it to a website, say for instance, compareTheMarket website, and I basically want the website to use that value, to return to me a list of insurances with different insurance prices based on that value.

I have not been able to find anything conclusive on this, and was hoping someone could provide some guidance on what I could do to achieve this? So far I've found GET Requests, but that does not seem to help with my particular problem.

Comment: did you ever hear about API and RESTfull services?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a website that can do this. You can use json to;

1. Pass your value to a PHP Script
2. Do necessary comparison on PHP script
3. Return result to app with json